# Find all solutions to $y'=3x^2+2x+1/(y-2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all solutions to $y'=3x^2+2x+1/(y-2)$

I am stuck at $y^2-4y=x^3+x^2+x+c$

Comment: You forgot a factor 2 before integrating...otherwise your integration is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'=\dfrac {3x^2+2x+1}{y-2}$$
I guess that's what you meant.
$$2y'(y-2)=2(3x^2+2x+1)$$
$$y^2-4y=2(x^3+x^2+x+c)$$
Complete the square:
$$y^2-4y+4=2(x^3+x^2+x+C)$$
$$(y-2)^2=2(x^3+x^2+x+C)$$
$$y(x)=2\pm \sqrt {2(x^3+x^2+x+C)}$$